# What's the most efficient way get the first day of the current month?

Tags: ruby, datetime

With ruby I'm trying to get format a date as such: 2009-10-01

Where I take the current date (2009-10-26) and then change the day to "01".

I know of ways to do this, but was curious what the shortest way is, code wise, to pull this off.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Time.parse("2009-10-26").strftime("%Y-%m-01")
```

Comment: Thanks...writing from the future and this worked for me  =)

Answer (score 70):

If you don't mind including ActiveSupport in your application, you can simply do this:

```
require 'active_support'
date = Date.today.beginning_of_month
```

Comment: I get `require': cannot load such file -- activesupport (LoadError)`.

Comment: require 'active_support'

Answer (score 15):

```
require 'date'    
now = Date.today
Date.new(now.year, now.month, 1)
```

Comment: be careful with leading zeros in unquoted integers: that's octal notation. It'll work fine until you type 08 or 09.

Comment: Fixed the now and the day problem. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Most efficient to get start and end date of current month

```
@date = DateTime.now   
@date.beginning_of_month
@date.end_of_month
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the date object without ActiveSupport, you can go back to the last day of the last month and sum 1.

```
Date.today - Date.today.mday + 1
```

Comment: I think you should change it to
`Date.today - Date.today.mday + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Like

```
Date.today.beginning_of_day
Date.today.end_of_day
```

And

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week
Date.today.end_of_week
```

There also is

```
Date.today.beginning_of_year
Date.today.end_of_year
```

Answer (score 0):

This works...

Not terribly clever :/

```
require 'date'
Date.parse(Date.parse("2009-10-26").to_s[0,8] << "01")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
Date.today.beginning_of_month
```

Comment: This returns the first day of the year, not of the month.